# rails db migrate locally-Multiple migrations have the version number

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose

I'm using docker, and I'm trying to run migrations locally using

```
docker-compose run app rails db:migrate
```

I'm getting an error though:

```
Multiple migrations have the version number 20211230114441.
```

I tried searching for this migration in db/migrate but nothing's there. I also tried checking out different versions of `schema.rb` but this fixed nothing.

Since I'm running using docker, and even though, my files are attached to a volume, I tried using `docker-compose build` before running again to make sure that the migration files are udpated. Again fixed nothing.

Any ideas on how this can be fixed?

Comment: Please ensure that you've only got one migration. Try deleting *this particular file* and run docker command.

Comment: Just tried this, didnt work as well unfortunately